# Does Homebrew have a programmatic API

Tags: node.js, homebrew

Can you use Homebrew directly in Ruby, or in Node.js? I know you can in let's say Node.js, run terminal commands through a child process, but is there like a *binding* to Homebrew in any language so that you can use its features programmatically?

In Ruby that might look like:

```
Brew::Installer.install :imagemagick
```

Or in Node.js:

```
brew.install('imagemagick')
  .on('progress', amount => console.log(amount))
  .on('end', function(){
    console.log('Installed!')
  })
```

Does any such thing exist? If so, where can I find a hello world example? I've searched around Google and GitHub but didn't find anything. Hesitating digging into the Homebrew source.

If nothing exists, would it be straightforward to add? What are your thoughts in that case?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=Homebrew, https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Homebrew

Comment: I wish it existed but Homebrew doesn’t have such API. Although it’s better now than a year ago, Homebrew still does _a lot_ of things in the command handling rather than in its internals. You could e.g. run `Homebrew.install_formula Formula["git"]` to install git, but if it’s already installed it’ll just print an error message and return `true`. I’m sure PRs to change that would be welcome, though.